# how to call a function whose name is the same of the local variable name in c

Tags: c

How can i call a function whose name is same as that of the local variable in a calling function

Scenario:

I need to call a function myfun(a,b) from some other function otherfun(int a,int myfun) . How can i do it?

```
int myfun(int a , int b)
{
 //
//
return 0;
}


int otherfun(int a, int myfun)
{
 // Here i need to call the function myfun as .. myfun(a,myfun)
 // how can i do this?? Please help me out

}
```

Comment: You can't. Just rename the parameter.

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to do this, but strictly speaking, it would be wrong to do so. Your best to change the name of one of them.

Comment: Why would you want such a thing? Even if it was possible, it would be completely weird.

Comment: For all the people that said, "just rename the parameter".  What if you didn't write it?  For example, what about myfun(int num, int div),  and you want to call the standard library div function?  Without easy ways to do namespaces in C, you have to work with the namespace constructs that C does provide.

Comment: @Josh: If you're writing code in the body of `myfun(int num, int div)`, and you want to call a function named `div`, then you *can* rename the parameter of `myfun`. You might want to also change the name of the same parameter in the corresponding header file and documentation, but you don't *have* to do that just because you've renamed it in the function definition. If you didn't then you'd probably want to leave a comment to that effect, though, so that anyone reading the source understands why they aren't seeing the parameter names they expected.

Comment: @Steve, sometimes when you are working with others, and with legacy projects, the renaming is not always so simple. (yes, technically it can be done, but sometimes there are reasons not to.)  The aliasing technique that Luther showed is sometimes helpful.

Answer (score 8):

```
int myfun(int a , int b)
{
return 0;
}

int myfun_helper(int a, int b) 
{
 return myfun(a,b);
}
int otherfun(int a, int myfun)
{
 /* the optimizer will most likely inline this! */
 return myfun_helper(a,myfun);
}
```

Comment: Inside of `otherfun` what is `b`?  You mean `myfun`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable keeping a pointer to the `myfun()` function. This will allow you to effectively 'alias' the original function without introducing an additional one.

```
int myfun(int a, int b)
{
    // ...
    return 0;
}

static int (*myfunwrap)(int, int) = &myfun;

int otherfun(int a, int myfun)
{
    myfunwrap(a, myfun);
}
```

Of course, you can replace `myfunwrap` with any name you like.

Answer (score 0):

The best idea would be to just chose a different name for your parameter. The second best is this one, I think:

```
int otherfun(int a, int myfun)
{
 int myfun_tmp = myfun;
 // Here i need to call the function myfun as .. myfun(a,myfun)
 {
   extern int myfun(int, int);
   myfun(a, myfun_tmp);
 }
}
```